# JasperException: equal symbol expected

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring form tag library & a [select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) jquery plugin

An error occurs on running the jsp

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/view/home.jsp(51,4)
>   /WEB-INF/view/createpost.jsp(19,15) equal symbol expected

```
     <li>
        <form:select name="mood" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-sm" 
                        multiple data-width="100px" data-size="5"  //Line 19
                        title='Feeling' path="mood">
                            <option value="1">A</option>
                            <option value="2">B</option>
                            <option value="3">C</option>
                        </form:select>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <form:select name="Working" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-sm" 
                        data-width="110px" data-size="5" title='WorkingAt ..' path="WorkingAt">
                            <option value="1">A</option>
                        </form:select>
                </li>
```

When I remove the `multiple` attribute from the first select tag, error disappears, but if effects the functionality. `multiple` attribute enables multiple value selection in the select tag.

Seems like spring form is not allowing `multiple` attribute to run.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when i try to add disebbled `selected disabled` after adding it like below problem got solved.

```
<form:option value="0" label="Membership Type" selected="true" disabled="true"/>
```

for your answer,

```
<option value="1" multiple="true">A</option>
```